# Element passed in many recursive slots not showing up in bottom level element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

Using Polymer 1.* and shady dom with Chrome.

**UPDATE**: I can pass a element through 2 named slots but not 3. Does shady dom have a limit?

I am having issues passing `special-form-element` in `<foo-two>`'s `slot="card-content"` and making it show in the great grandchild elements `<foo-card>`'s `<slot name="card-content"></slot>`.

The card footer with `<slot name="footer-action-right"></slot>` shows the paper-buttons with no issues(so iron collapse is expanded as it should be). It's only the `<slot name="card-content"></slot>` that is not showing the `special-form-element` passed in through the many recursive slots.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong to not make the `special-form-element` show in `<foo-card>`'s `<slot name="card-content"></slot>`?

```
<dom-module id="foo-one">
  <template>
    <foo-two>
      <special-form-element id="addForm" slot="card-content" client="[[client]]" entity="{{newEntity}}"></special-form-element>
    </foo-two>
 </template>
</dom-module>
```

---

```
<dom-module id="foo-two">
  <template>
    <foo-three id="addForm">
      <paper-button slot="button" on-tap="goToGrid">Cancel</paper-button>

      <div slot="card-content">
        <slot id="addSlot" name="card-content"></slot>
      </div>
    </foo-three>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

---

```
<dom-module id="foo-three">
  <template>
    <bar-element></bar-element>

     <foo-card hidden="[[bar]]">
       <slot name="header-content"></slot>

       <div id="addSlot" slot="card-content">
         <slot name="card-content"></slot>
       </div>

       <div slot="footer-action-right">
         <paper-button on-tap="_submitForm">Save</paper-button>
         <paper-button
           on-tap="_cancel"
           hidden$="[[hideCancel]]"
           slot="footer-action-right">
           Cancel
         </paper-button>

         <slot name="buttonn"><slot>
       </div>           

    </foo-card>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

---

```
<dom-module id="foo-card">
  <template>
    <div id="mainCard" class="sp6-paper-card">
      <div class="card-header-bar" hidden="[[minimal]]">
        <sp-letter-avatar hidden="[[noLetterAvatar]]" id="headerAvatar" width="40" height="40" name="[[name]]" label="[[label]]"></sp-letter-avatar>
        <span class="card-title" hidden="[[_hideHeading(noLetterAvatar, heading)]]">[[heading]]</span>
        <div class="layout horizontal">
          <paper-icon-button icon="hardware:keyboard-arrow-down"
                             noink
                             hidden$="[[!collapsible]]"
                             id="collapseButton"
                             title="{{title}}"
                             on-tap="_expand">
          </paper-icon-button>

          <slot name="button"></slot>

        </div>
      </div>

      <iron-collapse opened="[[!minimized]]">

        <iron-collapse id="expandedContent" opened="[[expanded]]">
          <div class="card-content">
            <slot name="card-content"></slot>
          </div>

          <div class="card-footer" hidden="[[minimal]]">
            <slot name="footer-action-left"></slot>
            <div></div> <!-- flex filler -->
            <slot name="footer-action-right"></slot>
          </div>
        </iron-collapse>

      </iron-collapse>
    </div>

  </template>
</dom-module>
```